# How to handle composite keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn Rails, and am unsure of the Rails way of (or alternative to) dealing with composite keys.

Suppose I have a table of countries -- lets say I use the ISO 3166-1 codes, and pick the Alpha2 code as the key. I think the Rails thing to do would be to call that `id`, right? So I have COUNTRIES = (*id*, alpha3_code, numeric_code, name)

Now, each country can have many ISO 3166-2 regions, so I have REGIONS = (*id*, *country_id*, name). I tell rails that COUNTRIES has_many REGIONS and that REGIONS belongs_to COUNTRIES (am I right so far? Apart from the capitalisation, of course.) The region ID's are unique within a country, but not necessarily globally, so I need the composite key.

So now I have company offices, each of which is in a particular region. But I can only specify a region with a [country, region] pair, and I understand Rails doesn't like composite keys. So what *is* the Rails way to organise this, so that given an office I can, for instance, determine its region and country, and given a country can find all the states in that country?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Ah! I don't see it with add_many :through, but a bit further down the page I see has_one :through, which looks right for the situation I describe.

Comment: But of course, not all countries have regions, do they,  so you're right, has_many :through is the right structure. If you'd posted that as an answer rather than a comment I could have given you the rep for the answer.